# Vector vs Deque Insertion Time

Tags: c++, vector, stl, containers, deque

I read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5425/An-In-Depth-Study-of-the-STL-Deque-Container) nice experiment comparing, in particular, the performance of calling `insert()` on both a `vector` and a `deque` container.  The result from that particular experiment (Experiment 4) was that `deque` is vastly superior for this operation.

I implemented my own test using a short sorting function I wrote, which I should note uses the `[]` operator along with other member functions, and found vastly different results.  For example, for inserting 100,000 elements, `vector` took 24.88 seconds, while `deque` took 374.35 seconds.

How can I explain this?  I imagine it has something to do with my sorting function, but would like the details!

I'm using g++ 4.6 with no optimizations.

Here's the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

size_t InsertionIndex(vector<double>& vec, double toInsert) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    if (toInsert < vec[i])
      return i;
  return vec.size();  // return last index+1 if toInsert is largest yet                                                                          
}

size_t InsertionIndex(deque<double>& deq, double toInsert) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < deq.size(); ++i)
    if (toInsert < deq[i])
      return i;
  return deq.size();  // return last index+1 if toInsert is largest yet                                                                          
}

int main() {
  vector<double> vec;
  deque<double> deq;

  size_t N = 100000;

  clock_t tic = clock();
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    double val = rand();
        vec.insert(vec.begin() + InsertionIndex(vec, val), val);
    //        deq.insert(deq.begin() + InsertionIndex(deq, val), val);                                                                           
  }

  float total = (float)(clock() - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  cout << total << endl;
}
```

Comment: Tell us: 1) What compiler you're using and 2) Whether you're testing an optimized build or not.

Comment: Just added that I'm using g++ with no optimizations, but I'm not sure how to find out which g++ version I'm using.

Comment: vector of double would be possibly faster, but if the class type is big, deque would be for sure faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special case where `deque` can be much faster than `vector` is when you're inserting at the *front* of the container. In your case you're inserting at random locations, which will actually give the advantage to `vector`.

Also unless you're using an optimized build, it's quite possible that there are bounds checks in the library implementation. Those checks can add significantly to the time. To do a proper benchmark comparison you must run with all normal optimizations turned on and debug turned off.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that.  My compiler command was just `g++ filename.cpp`.  Do I need to add anything to turn debug off, and which optimization should I use?  E.g. -o2?

Comment: @bcf: For gcc, the default implementation does not use checked iterators, so just bumping the optimizer up (-O2 or -O3) should suffice. But the important part in the comparison is what Mark mentions in the first paragraph. The advantage of deque is insertions and deletions in the *front* (which incidentally is mentioned in the article you linked)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is performing an insertion sort, which is O(n^2).  Iterating over a `deque` is slower than iterating over a `vector`.

I suspect the reason you are not seeing the same result as the posted link is because the run-time of your program is dominated by the loop in `InsertionIndex` not the call to `deque::insert` (or `vector::insert`.